# Не работает js на моб устройствах

Tags: javascript, android

В браузерах на андроидах не работает выпадающие меню на сайте.
  JS код:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

load([...document.querySelectorAll('img')]);

function load(imgs) {
  let img = imgs.shift();
  imgs.length && (img.onload = load.bind(0, imgs));
  img.setAttribute('src', img.getAttribute('src'));
}


   // mobile menu toggling
    $("#menu_icon").click(function(){
        $("header nav ul").toggleClass("show_menu");
        $("#menu_icon").toggleClass("close_menu");
        return false;
    });


    //Contact Page Map Centering
    var hw = $('header').width() + 50;
    var mw = $('#map').width();
    var wh = $(window).height();
    var ww = $(window).width();

    $('#map').css({
        "max-width" : mw,
        "height" : wh
    });

    if(ww>1100){
         $('#map').css({
            "margin-left" : hw
        });
    }


}
```

Comment: Может быть, используется устаревший браузер, не поддерживающий ES6?

Comment: Андроиды очень разные и браузеров на них сильно больше одного. И я на 146% уверен, что большинство из них не умеют spread operator (это как минимум).